# Proof that $T_i \unlhd T$

Tags: group-theory

In the context of translation planes and translation groups I would like to prove to following. Suppose we have a group $T$ with some subgroups $T_i$ ($i\in I$) with the following properties.
$$ T_i \leq T $$
$$ T_i \cap T_j = \{1\} $$
$$ T_iT_j=T $$
$$ \cup_i T_i = T $$
for every $i,j \in I$ with $i\neq j$. Now I would like to prove that the subgroups $T_i$ are normal subgroups. Actually, I want to prove that the group T is abelian but I have a proof for this fact when I know that the groups are normal subgroups.

Comment: In this generality, it is not going to work. For instance $S_{3}$ is the product of a subgroup of order $3$ and one of order $2$, and the latter is not normal. You must have some extra hypothesis.

Comment: Any *finite* group which is not nilpotent (and thus not the direct product of its Sylow subgroups) has the same problem Andreas mentioned as at least one of the Sylow sbgps. is not normal (and, of course, the group isn't abelian). You have to have more conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Probably, what I want to do only works under the extra hypothesis that those subgroups are normal subgroups.

Comment: Even then you can't, in general, deduce $\,T\,$ is abelian, @mvcouwen . Check what it is you have and what you would *realistically* want to get.

Comment: Oops, now I see i forgot to mention that $\cup_i T_i = T$.